# Auth middleware always print undefined role

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm creating e-commerce app with express and mysql for my backend. I need to protect my route using middleware and check if the user is seller or customer, then I try to make the auth middleware but it still throws an error.

Here is middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const auth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Authentication failed',
      });
    }

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'JWT_SECRET');
    req.user = decodedToken;
    console.log(req.user.role);
    

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      data: error.message,
    });
  }
};

const isSeller = (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    //console.log(req.user.role);
    if (!req.user || req.user.role !== 'seller') {
      return res.status(403).json({
        status: 'error',
        error: 'User is not a seller',
      });
    }
    next();
  }catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  auth,
  isSeller,
};
```

I try to check why is it always throws an error and I put `console.log` to check it and it prints undefined. I need to know why it's undefined.

And here is token that is generated when the user logs in.

```
const token = jwt.sign(
    { 
      userId: existingUserByUsername.id,
      username: existingUserByUsername.username,
      email: existingUserByUsername.email,
      role: existingUserByUsername.role
    },
    'JWT_SECRET'
  );
  return token;
```

Comment: Well, you are setting `req.user` and then you console.log `req.decodedToken`, which you haven't set anywhere. That's why you get undefined. What error message do you get?

Comment: my bad, I wrote it wrong there, I tried several times with different things, starting from req.user.role to req.decodeToken, the result always throws undefined. because when I try to enter a user who has a seller role, it prints out that `user is not a seller` @Geshode

Comment: You do that within `isSeller`, right? Has `auth` always been called, before calling `isSeller`? Because you set `req.user` in `auth`, so it would be undefined, if you call `isSeller` without having called `auth`.

Comment: yes, auth always been called before calling isSeller. this is one of my route `router.post('/', authMiddleware.auth, authMiddleware.isSeller, productController.createProduct);` isSeller always throws `user is not a seller` even though i try to login a seller @Geshode

Comment: How do you set the token in the headers?

Comment: i set it in bearer token type in postman authorization @Geshode

Answer (score 0):

I skip your codes just follow this steps

first define auth middleware

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
//your codes
//extend request object
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'JWT_SECRET');; 
req.user =  decodedToken;
 }
```

apply authMiddleware to to routes

```
app.get('/somePath',authMiddleware, isSeller );
```

finally receive extend request object

```
const  isSeller = (req, res, next) => {
// extract user object
  const userObject =req.user;
 // your codes
 }
```